# Predict numbers from labeled images

Tags: image, numbers, label, predict

I am currently having the following problem:
The data includes 10,000 labeled images. The images contain sequences of numbers, each label corresponding to the number in that image. Image size is 70x300 (height: 70)
Example: The image contains the number 123 then the label will be 123

I need to build a model to predict what the number in the new image is worth.
Example: The image contains the number 999, the predicted result will be 999

I did my research and found very few websites that addressed this issue